# Assigning labels to values

Tags: r

I have a dataset with numbers 1:70 which correspond to a neighborhood name within a city.  The data is set up like so:

```
    Date | Area | Count
   04/16    1       12
   04/16    1       1
   05/16    2       3
   06/16    3       10
```

I have another dataframe with the area number and corresponding area name.

```
Number | Name
  1       Franklin
  2       State
```

How can I assign the area number value to its corresponding name without having to type out each number and name?

Comment: using `match`  ~~ `dat$new=dat1$Name[match(dat$Area,dat1$Number)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `match`

```
## Your data
dat = read.table(text="   Date  Area  Count
   04/16    1       12
   04/16    1       1
   05/16    2       3
   06/16    3       10",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

areas = read.table(text="Number  Name
  1       Franklin
  2       State",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

areas$Name[match(dat$Area, areas$Number)]
[1] "Franklin" "Franklin" "State"    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you give us reproducible data, but something like this:

```
df1$AreaName <- df2$Name[match(df1$Area, df2$Area)]
```